# What does "Not connected to AUT Agent" on Eclipse means?

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-mars

My Eclipse status bar is showing this weird message and refuses tu run Junit tests:
[image]

My question is:

- What does this message means?
- Has it anything to do with my problem with running Junit tests?

I am using eclipse Mars:

```
Version: Mars.2 (4.5.2)
Build id: M20160212-1500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Eclipse [Bug 484390](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484390).  The relevant discussion is near the bottom.

"but i found the problem.
it was an error in the AUT configuration.
i had typed into the field "Executable File Name" the path to the .bat with which i used to start the gui. but that seems to be wrong.
now i give this field the path to the java.exe,
the "AUT Working Directory" the path to the \lib dir where the jars are
and as "AUT Arguments" -classpath "file1.jar,file2.jar,..." .
that worked and the object mapping mode shows me some green highlighting."

Comment: I accept the answer at the best for the moment. But I solved the issue without any change in configuration. Tried to close eclipse and the saving process hanged. After waiting a long time I killed eclipse and after restarting It worked OK.

Comment: With Eclipse, you need to restart when certain changes are made. I have been bitten that way before.  That is why Restart is one of the options on the File pulldown. :-)